# Default function parameter as an initialized structure C++

Tags: c++

how to create default function parameter as a structure with initialized member?

```
#if defined(MIDL_PASS)
typedef struct _LARGE_INTEGER {
#else // MIDL_PASS
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } u;
#endif //MIDL_PASS
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;

LARGE_INTEGER g_l;

void journal(void *foo, const int bar, const LARGE_INTEGER& offsetToHistory = g_l )
{
   return;
}


int main()
{
   g_l.QuadPart = 0;
   LARGE_INTEGER li;
   li.QuadPart = 0;
   journal(NULL, 15, const_cast<LARGE_INTEGER&>(li));
   //I want this the below line to work as well the above.
   //journal(NULL, 15);
}
```

How to achieve this without using global variable "g_l". Actually, it's used in constructor prototype, so we can't use global varible.
Also I don't want to overload constructor.

Comment: "Also I don't want to overload constructor." - If you want to be able to say, `LARGE_INTEGER li = 5`, that is exactly what you need to do.

Comment: what about pointers instead of reference?

Comment: Or, a static class member with the default parameter?

Comment: or overloaded method with less parameters...

Comment: @ZacHowland  "LARGE_INTEGER li = 5" is not possible, cannot convert from "int" into "LARGE_INTEGER"

Comment: @JoeZ good try. But there is a problem of constructor's low flexibility, don't want to change existing code, it's better to add new code(new contructor), than changing the code which I didn't write.

Comment: @V-X with less parameters? what do you mean? factoring out the general code to some "init" function and creating small contstructor which will call that "init"?

Comment: @UnhandledExceptio - if you want to use literals then try `LARGE_INTEGER li = 5LL;`

Comment: @Sean same error: cannot convert from "__int64" into "LARGE_INTEGER". error C2440. there is no such constructor or the constructor overload resolution is ambigious. Please, refer to the LARGE_INTEGER structure.

Comment: @UnhandledException My point was that you said you did not want to write a conversion constructor, but if your goal is to be able to write code like that you **will** have to write conversion constructors.

Comment: @ZacHowland it's okay, we just talk about different constructors. When I say "don't want to overload constructor", I mean my own journal::journal() constructor, but seems to me, you are talking about converstion construction for the LARGE_INTEGER structure, right?

Comment: I have googled infro about constructor for structures, and I have learned that there is no proper constructor for LARGE_INTEGER to convert from int to LARGE_INTEGER. So there is an additional option to write my own structure inherited from LARGE_INTEGER with desired conversion constructor.

Comment: @UnhandledException So the `LARGE_INTEGER` structure you are using here is not your own, but that from some library?

Comment: @ZacHowland exactly, it's from windows header file.

Comment: @UnhandledException In that case, why use it at all?  `__int64` or `long long` will give you a 64-bit integer that actually is supported natively.